# Deploying Django to a server

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, web-deployment

This is an edit of my original question, which was how to successfully deploy a Django app to a server, because this was my first time. 
The following links are what I tried:

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04
2. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html
3. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04
4. https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/deploy-django-applications-using-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04
5. http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

I followed these to the letter, I got upto the part with `~/myproject/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` but then where they show that navigating to the servers ip address on port 8000 shows an 'It worked' page, I get no response. I also ran

```
# test.py
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"] # python3
    #return ["Hello World"] # python2
```

with `uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file test.py`, and still no response.

So after a while of banging my head against a wall, I decided to give up and skip past that part, and go straight for combining NGINX, uWSGI and my Django app. I just managed to get it working, so I will post a detailed solution below of exactly how I did that, hopefully it may help somebody else, as I found most of the instructions on the internet didn't explain somethings that I felt needed explaining to fully understand what was happening. That will suffice as a question and answer,...

*although* on a side note, I'm still interested in as to why without the installation of a webserver, I was still not able to visit the Django app ran with the command `runserver`, if you know, please comment.

Comment: Given that you have tried two completely different things - accessing Django via the development server, and accessing a simple WSGI app via uwsgi - and neither of them work, it seems likely that the problem is with your server itself. (Obviously the problem is not with the database or the static files, since your second attempt doesn't even use Django at all.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a while of scratching my head, I managed to successfully deploy my Django application to a server hosted on Digitalocean, with NGINX and uWSGI. I'm not going to post the IP of my actual server here, so in this answer I will use 10.11.12.13 as the IP address of my ubuntu server, . I did my best to backtrace my steps, the following is in chronological order:

1. Created a droplet on Digitalocean with Ubuntu 16.04.3 x64 with no 'additional options', then by email received the password for the root login:
2. Log into the new server and setup a new password 

   `➜ ssh root@10.11.12.13`

   Update the system:

   `# sudo apt-get update`
3. Add a new user *jupiar* and give it superuser privilege 

   `# sudo adduser jupiar && usermod -aG sudo jupiar`
4. Switch to user *jupiar*

   `# su - jupiar`
5. Install NGINX webserver

   `$ sudo apt-get install nginx`
6. I do a lot with data science, and my Django app uses alot of these features, so I prefer to work with Anaconda python as it's more complete from the start, so here download and install Anaconda python:

   `$ wget https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-5.0.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh` 

   `$ bash Anaconda3-5.0.0.1-Linux-x86_64.sh`

   *Noting that in the installation, Anaconda3 was installed to /home/jupiar/anaconda3, and i chose `[yes]` to have the installer prepend the install location to PATH in the `.bashrc`*
7. Now to restart bash:

   `$ . .bashrc`

   `$ source .bashrc`
8. Now I created a python virtual environment, and then activated it:

   `$ conda create -n drfprojectenv python=3.6 anaconda`

   `$ source activate drfprojectenv`
9. Now install Django and then start a new project

   `(drfprojectenv)$ pip install Django`

   `(drfprojectenv)$ django-admin.py startproject drfproject`
10. Setup the database:

    `(drfprojectenv)$ cd drfproject`

    `(drfprojectenv)~/drfproject$ ./manage.py migrate`
11. Set a static directory:

    `(drfprojectenv)~/drfproject$ echo 'STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")' >> drfproject/settings.py`
12. Collect the static files:

    `(drfprojectenv)~/drfproject$ ./manage.py collectstatic`
13. Now to install uWSGI, we need a few packages for the operating system so as to compile C code, for which uWSGI needs:

    `(drfprojectenv)~/drfproject$ sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python3-dev`

    `(drfprojectenv)~/drfproject$ cd`

    `(drfprojectenv)$ pip install uwsgi`
14. Okay, now is where it got a little more interesting: We now need to create an initialization file (.ini) for our Django project:

    `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/uwsgi/sites` 

    *(The `-p` just ables us to make all necessary parent directories)*

    `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo nano /etc/uwsgi/sites/drfproject.ini`

    And inside that file place the following:

    ```
    [uwsgi]
    project = drfproject
    base = /home/jupiar

    chdir = %(base)/%(project)
    home = %(base)/Env/%(project)
    module = %(project).wsgi:application

    master = true
    processes = 2

    socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
    chmod-socket = 666
    vacuum = true
    ```
15. Now we need to make a uWSGI service, we can do that by:

    `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service`

    and then inside that file place:

    ```
    [Unit]
    Description=uWSGI Emperor service
    After=syslog.target

    [Service]
    ExecStart=/home/jupiar/anaconda3/envs/drfprojectenv/bin/uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/sites/drfproject.ini
    Restart=always
    KillSignal=SIGQUIT
    Type=notify
    StandardError=syslog
    NotifyAccess=all

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
    ```
16. Now, we want uWSGI to start automatically on a system restart, and activate the service:

    `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo systemctl uwsgi enable`

    `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo systemctl uwsgi start`

    *Noting, that you may see:*

    `Warning: emperor.uwsgi.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.`

    *Where we would just run:*

    `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
17. Check the service is running properly with:

    `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo systemctl status uwsgi.service`

    *Where we should see something like:*

    ```
    uwsgi.service - uWSGI Emperor service
        Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
        Active: active (running)
    ```

    18. Start the service with this command too:

        `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo service uwsgi start`
    19. Now we need to configure NGINX:

        `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

        *and then place the following*

    ```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name _;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/drfproject;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/jupiar/drfproject/drfproject.sock;
    }


    }
    ```

    20. Make sure that Django's ALLOWED_HOSTS have some combination of the following ip addresses:

        `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.11.12.13', '*', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']`
    21. Now stop and start uWSGI service, and restart nginx:

        `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo service uwsgi stop`

        `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo service uwsgi start`

        `(drfprojectenv)$ sudo service nginx restart`
    22. And that should be roughly it, all the steps I could backtrace are there. One thing you may need to do aswell is to install Django and uwsgi on the global installation of Anaconda, as well as within the virtual environment. 

        Now that's installed properly, should be pretty effortless to switch it over to the rest framework.

Answer (score 0):

So lets start with the configuration of your droplet on DigitalOcean. Which flavour of linux are you using?  (Ubuntu or Debian etc) and which webserver (Nginx or Apache2 etc)
I set up a Debian droplet on Digitalocean a few months ago doing my own install with Apache webserver and it is all running fine. I always install a virtualenv inside my project library and pip install everything I need in that. So I would suggest going back to this arrangement rather than having it external to the project.  Once I have my structure in place, have set my settings.py file my wsgi.py file and have collected my static files etc, I then configure my database using migration etc.  Then lastly I configure my webserver to find the location of project. In apache2 you need to configure a .conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and then enable it in sites-enabled using sudo a2ensite .conf.  There will be a  comparable setup in nginx and you probably know more about that than I do having deployed Angular applications in the past.  So check these major steps and see if it flags up anything you may have missed.

Comment: Im using Ubuntu 16.04.3, and in my question, I hadn't even installed nginx or any webserver yet, and I have tried three atempts with python, one with virtualenvs in the project, no virtualenvs at all, and even used Anacoda's virtualenvs too. Right now I have installed nginx and trying to configure uwsgi, but having problems with ExecStart giving an error of 203/Exec

Answer (score 0):

For deploy django project on server , You must do the following steps step by step:

**0#** Get Backup From Your Project Files

**1#** create the python-app through the server panel.

(if your server panel is cpanel, look for the 'setup python app')

**2#** upload *'static'* and *'media'* files in *public_html* directory in *'file manager'* on server.

**3#** look for the directory in the *'file manager'* in the panel server with the name of python app,  that you created and upload your project files into it.

**4#** edit *settings.py* file in your project :

> DEBUG = FALSE

**5#** edit *settings.py* file in your project :

> ALLOWED_HOSTS = [     'yourdomain' ,  'www.yourdomain' ,
> 'https://...' ,  ]

**6#** edit *settings.py* file in your project :
change the addressing of the *'media'* and *'static'* directories from the *'os.path'* to the actual address of these folders on the server, such as:

> STATIC_ROOT = '/home/username/app_name/static'
>
> MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/username/app_name/media'

[ these steps are general and you may need additional settings for different servers. ]